# Get Cities around 100 KM radius with place id of google places

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I have place id of a city Vijayawada, Andhra Prades, India. and its place id is ChIJS5QtSPnvNToRZQJKq4R-m5M

Now using google places api, how do we get cities and their place ids around this city within 100KM range.

```
function initialize() {
        var options = {
              types: ['(cities)'],
              componentRestrictions: {country: "in"}
             };
        var input = document.getElementById('location_city');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {    
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            console.log("Place ID is " + place.place_id);       
        });     
   }
```

Comment: You'll get better answers if you show what you've tried, but basically look up the "Place Details" then use the latitude/longitude to do a "Place Search"

Comment: @doublesharp updated code that place_id is strored in db, now how do it use this place id to get cities within 100 KM range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PlaceDetails responses returned from this

```
  json = $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJS5QtSPnvNToRZQJKq4R-m5M&key=YOUR_API_KEY')
```

And find the location property

```
  var lng = json.result.geometry.location.lat
  var lng = json.result.geometry.location.lng
```

Then the radius should be entered, in KM

```
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  var pyrmont = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
  placeResults = service.nearbySearch({
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 1000 // meters
  }, callback);
```

The return value `placeResults` is an array of places, each with placeIds

Comment: How do i get those lat and lng values from the autocomplete variable ??

Comment: instead to store search, can we search other cities around that location ?

Comment: this solution, i.e. server side geocoding, is fine if you're not expecting to exceed the daily limit of 2500 requests. If you are, then you should geocode client side.